# Error: Cannot find module 'C:\...\node_modules\truffle\build\cli.bundled.js' after installation done

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, npm-install, truffle

I installed the latest version of truffle by `npm install -g truffle`. The installation done and this is the last few lines of the result on PowerShell:

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\bufferutil
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-gyp-build
npm ERR! The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-03-10T14_51_51_312Z-debug-0.log
```

And I tried `truffle --version` to check if it was installed successfully or not, but this is the result:

```
PS C:\Users\lenovo> truffle --version
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1042
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\cli.bundled.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1039:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:885:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v18.13.0
```

This error throwed because `cli.bundled.js` module can't be found in the given directory:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\cli.bundled.js'
```

As I checked, There is not any `truffle` folder in that directory and so the mentioned module can't be found there. It seems Truffle installation should create `truffle` folder in that directory but it don't. Is the installation incomplete or it creates that folder in another directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The cause of the problem:**

**1)** As I said in the question, `truffle` folder doesn't exist in the both directories mentioned by the errors:

```
C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\bufferutil
```

And

```
C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\cli.bundled.js
```

And the installation is incomplete. Because we shouldn't install truffle by the latest version of npm, we should install it by version 6 of npm.

**2)** There is an error in the last few lines of installation process (There is in the question):

```
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-gyp-build
```

That says `node-gyp-build` module doesn't work or doesn't exist. [node-gyp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-gyp) is a cross-platform command-line tool written in Node.js for compiling native addon modules for Node.js. [node-gyp-build](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-gyp-build) is a build tool and bindings loader for `node-gyp` that supports prebuilds. It seems the system that is installing truffle lacks the both them.

**Solution:**

1. Uninstall Truffle: `npm uninstall -g truffle`.
2. Delete all Truffle's files and folders. Some directories like
   `C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm`,
   `C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules`,
   `C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Roaming` and so on, may have Truffle's files
   and folders.
3. Delete all files associated to `node-gyp` and `node-gyp-build` if you
   have some of them. Some directory like
   `C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm` may have them.
4. Delete node_modules folder from `C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm`.
5. Change the version of npm to 6: `npm install -g npm@6`.
6. Install node-gyp: `npm install -g node-gyp`.
7. Install node-gyp-build: `npm install -g node-gyp-build`.
8. Install canvas: `npm install -g canvas`.
9. Install Solidity compiler: `npm install -g solc`.
10. Install Truffle: `npm install -g truffle`.
11. Change the version of npm to the latest: `npm install -g npm@latest`.